# template friend operator new mingw32

Tags: c++, templates, operator-keyword, friend

My understanding is that operator new cannot be templated (when declared using the parameters I have used.. (size_t)

The following compiles OK on mingw32 and arduino DUE, but not on other platforms e.g. linux.

Is there a bug in mingw32, or should this be allowed on other targets too ?

```
class t_other_class
{
  public:

  // This form of operator new is ***NOT*** allowed to be templated.
  void*                  operator new     ( size_t            arg1  ) ;

  // This form of operator new CAN be templated, and IS.
  template<typename TF>
  void*                  operator new     ( size_t            arg1
                                          , int               arg2
                                          ) ;

  // This form of operator new CAN be templated, but IS NOT.
  void*                  operator new     ( size_t            arg1
                                          , int               arg2
                                          , int               arg3
                                          ) ;
};



template <typename TCLASS>
class t_class
{
  public:

    // This form of operator new can NOT be templated, but is ALLOWED in mingw32
    template<typename TF> // THIS SHOULD GENERATE AN ERROR
    friend
    void*   t_other_class::operator new   ( size_t            arg1  ) ;


    // Examples of templating..
    template<typename TF>
    friend  /* IS templated in t_other_class*/
    void*   t_other_class::operator new   ( size_t            arg1
                                          , int               arg2
                                          ) ;
    template<typename TF>
    friend  /* IS NOT templated in t_other_class*/
    void*                  operator new   ( size_t            arg1
                                          , int               arg2
                                          , int               arg3
                                          ) ;
} ; 


/*
OK
====
windows
GNU C++ (GCC) version 4.8.2 (i686-w64-mingw32)
DUE
gcc version 4.8.3 20140228 (release) [ARM/embedded-4_8-branch revision 208322] (GNU Tools for ARM Embedded Processors)

Error
====
linux
GNU C++ (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) version 4.8.4 (i686-linux-gnu)
*/
```

Comment: "mingw32" if you mean mingw32-gcc, which version? "linux" there is more than one compiler for linux.

Comment: I have editied my question to show compiler versions

Comment: You're comparing different minor versions of gcc (all of them rather old) in addition to different targets. Get a current release (5.4 or 6.3).

Answer (score 0):

I updated to latest Mingw and it now correctly reports the misuse of template declaration (as per other compilers). Looks like old version of mingw was the problem.